# Deploy my project to the jelestic cloud

Tags: jar, applet, web-deployment, war

Being quite new to the web technologies in general,  I have been trying to deploy a project to the free Cloud named "jelestic". I am required to upload a .war.

The problem is that I have a folder containing a working applet, some  web pages  explaining its functionalities., and some library .jar that is necessary to make the applet work.  I don't see how to wrap the whole folder into a .war file.

Most tutorials tell me how to deploy an applet through localhost:8080. But here I would like to make a bundle of all the files in the folder and upload it as a .war file.

Could you tell me how to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your applet in some directory under war directory it will be publicly accessible. So if you place your applet and lib jar in let us say: app.war/applet/applet.jar app.war/applet/lib.jar all you will need is a page with applet tag poiting to `http://appserver/app/applet/applet.jar` :)

Comment: Thanks. Could you rephrase the response with commas please, but I am not sure I really understand it.